# Class initialization without () in c#

Tags: c#, constructor, initialization

In c# I used to init my class by calling default constructor. You can mention **()** after class name

```
var class = new MyClass()
{
   Property= 1,
   Property2 = "test"
}
```

But last time I see examples without **()**. Like this

```
var class = new MyClass
{
   Property= 1,
   Property2 = "test"
}
```

Is there any difference with and without ()?

Comment: No, there isn't any. It is the same thing. Just a syntatical sugar for parameterless Constructor.

Comment: @Sinatr Not a dup. Both code samples are object initializers.

Comment: @PatrickHofman, yes thanks, soon I will learn to read questions carefully ;)

Comment: As per question, you may want to call constructor with parameters, then you need bracers and parameters inside. If constructor is parameterless bracers are optional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature is called Object Initializer and it's been introduced in C#3.0.

When you use it, the `()` are redundant, so there is no difference between your two code samples

Answer (score 2):

There are no differences. If you use resharper, it mark this `()` as redundant.

You can use `()` or not, It depends on your style.

Answer (score 1):

As you see in the IL Code they are identical:

```
 internal class Program
    {
        public class MyClass
        {
        public int Property
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string Property2
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program.MyClass expr_06 = new Program.MyClass();
        expr_06.Property = 1;
        expr_06.Property2 = "test";
        Program.MyClass expr_20 = new Program.MyClass();
        expr_20.Property = 1;
        expr_20.Property2 = "test";
    }
}
```